# SingleInstance activation at container build

Tags: autofac

I have a SingleInstance service that I need to be active very early in my application.  However, this service is maintained in a DLL that is consumed by other applications, so I'd prefer that this "early activation" be configured directly in the registration extensions/modules used to register the feature to which it related, rather than forcing the consumer to do a superfluous `Resolve` operation just to get the feature to work--or put another way, allowing them to forget to do it.

Is there an option in the fluent configuration for SingleInstance services that allows this? Or perhaps an event that I could hook into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into implementing [IStartable](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Startable).

Or, as @Travis points out, use the [`AutoActivate()`](http://autofac.org/apidoc/html/4B1E7BD9.htm) registration extension. This wraps the registration in an implicit `IStartable` and thus automatically activates the registration when the container is built.